# How to iterate through an array of objects and only collecting the data that a button holds

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently playing around with JavaScript and decided to make a cookie clicker game. At the moment, I can have each button hold a function which updates the soulAmount, sps and upgrade cost once the button has been clicked. However, when I create more buildings that the player can purchase, it's going to leave a lot of functions on my javascript file which I feel is unnecessary. I thought of creating an array of objects that hold the sps and upgrade cost data to refactor the code for efficiency since the only info that changes in the functions are the upgrade cost and the sps (souls per second). At the moment, when the player clicks on one of the buttons, it iterates through ALL the array objects instead of just the one that has been clicked. How do I fix this code?

```
let soulAmount = 0;
let soulAddition = 1;
let grabSps = document.querySelector(".sps").innerHTML;
let sps = parseInt(grabSps);
let upgrade1GOT = false;
let upgrade2GOT = false;

let buildings = [
    {
        "name": "Collector",
        "upgradecost": 10,
        "sps": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Hunter",
        "upgradecost": 100,
        "sps": 5
    }
];

let upgrades = document.querySelectorAll(".upgrade");

let firstbutton = document.getElementsByClassName("upgrade")[0];

upgrades.forEach(function (i) {
    i.addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (i = 0; i < buildings.length; i++) {
            if (soulAmount >= buildings[i].upgradecost) {
                sps += buildings[i].sps;
                soulAmount -= buildings[i].upgradecost;
                document.querySelector(".souls_amount").innerHTML = soulAmount;
                document.querySelector(".sps").innerHTML = sps;
                buildings[i].upgradecost = buildings[i].upgradecost + Math.round(buildings[i].upgradecost / 100 * 20);
                console.log(buildings[i].upgradecost);
                console.log(buildings[i].upgradecost);
            }
        }
    })
})



window.setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector(".souls_amount").innerHTML = soulAmount;
    document.querySelector(".upgrade1-cost").innerHTML = buildings[0].upgradecost;
    document.querySelector(".upgrade2-cost").innerHTML = buildings[1].upgradecost;
    validateSoul();
}, 1);

function validateSoul(){
    if(soulAmount >= 10 && soulAmount <= 19 && upgrade1GOT == false){
        document.getElementById("collect100").style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("collect100").disabled = true;
    } else if (soulAmount >= 20 && upgrade1GOT == false){
        document.getElementById("collect100").disabled = false;
    }

    if(soulAmount >= 100 && soulAmount <= 199 && upgrade2GOT == false){
        document.getElementById("collect1000").style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("collect1000").disabled = true;
    } else if (soulAmount >= 200 && upgrade2GOT == false){
        document.getElementById("collect1000").disabled = false;
    }

    if(soulAmount >= buildings[0].upgradecost) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("upgrade")[0].disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("upgrade")[0].disabled = true;
    }

    if(soulAmount >= buildings[1].upgradecost) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("upgrade")[1].disabled = false;
        document.querySelector(".soul__shop--name").innerHTML = "Hunter";
        document.querySelector(".upgrade2-cost").innerHTML = buildings[1].upgradecost;
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("upgrade")[1].disabled = true;
    }
}

function getSoul() {
    soulAmount += soulAddition;
    document.querySelector(".souls_amount").innerHTML = soulAmount;
    return soulAmount;
}
```

My HTML is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/main.css">
    <title>Soul Clicker</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="soul">
        <div class="soul__interface">
            <h1 class="souls_amount">0</h1>
            <p class="sps-text"><span class="sps">0</span> Souls Per Second</p>
            <button class="soul_btn" onclick="getSoul()">THIS IS A SOUL</button>
        </div>
        <div class="soul__blank">

        </div>
        <div class="soul__shop">
            <div class="soul__shop--achievementcontainer">
                <button id="collect100" onclick="achievement1()">Buy</button>
                <button id="collect1000" onclick="achievement2()">Buy</button>
            </div>
            <div class="soul__shop--buildingcontainer">
                <div class="soul__shop--buildingcontainer--item">
                    <div>
                        <h2>Collector</h2>
                        <p class="upgrade1-cost"></p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="upgrade" id="0">Buy</button>
                </div>
                <div class="soul__shop--buildingcontainer--item">
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="soul__shop--name">???</h2>
                        <p class="upgrade2-cost">???</p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="upgrade" id="1">Buy</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
</body>
<script src="../dist/js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

I thought of using "let firstbutton = document.getElementsByClassName("upgrade")[0];" and changed the index of 0 to i, so that it only grabs that button's data, but I couldn't get it to work. So I'm hoping some genius on here can help me figure it out and I can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create your click events and link the clicked button to the corresponding data item.

```
upgrades.forEach(function (upgrade) {
    upgrade.addEventListener("click", function () {
        let current = this;
        let p = this.parentNode;
        let currentIndex = [...p.parentNode.children].indexOf(p);
        //the current cost is stored in buildings[currentIndex], perform your logic with that
    });
});
```

Proof-of-concept:

```js
let buildings = [
    {
        "name": "Collector",
        "upgradecost": 10,
        "sps": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Hunter",
        "upgradecost": 100,
        "sps": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "Fisher",
        "upgradecost": 1000,
        "sps": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "Cook",
        "upgradecost": 10000,
        "sps": 50
    },
];

for (let btn of document.querySelectorAll("#container input")) {
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(buildings[[...this.parentNode.children].indexOf(this)]);
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" value="Collector">
    <input type="button" value="Hunter">
    <input type="button" value="Fisher">
    <input type="button" value="Cook">
</div>
```

Note, that here the spread operator (the [...] part) is being used in order to convert `children` into actual array so that we can call `indexOf`